# How to consistently receive and use data from API?

Tags: c#, json, api

I am really new to c# and to learn how to use APIs I am making a username availability checker for Minecraft. I have written a semi-working checker code:

```
public async Task GetMojangItems(string username)
{
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync("" +
            "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username);

        if (response.Contains("name") == true)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = Color.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(" [-] " + username + " -> " + response);
        }
        else if (response.Contains("name") == false)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = Color.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(" [+] " + username + " -> " + response);
        }
}
```

And function that uses it:

```
private async void CheckUsernames()
{
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Username Checker Selected!");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Test username");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Import username list");
        Console.Write("\r\nSelect an option: ");

        if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
        {
            Console.Write("\r\nChoose a name to check: ");
            Program program = new Program();
            string nameimput = Console.ReadLine();
            await program.GetMojangItems(nameimput);
        }
}
```

But do not get reliable results, sometimes the checker will respond (Around 10% of the time) and most times it will not respond at all and will skip the name.

Additionally, I seem to have to include an additional check in the Main Task otherwise no checks will work at all;

```
await program.GetMojangItems("closingprogram!");
```

Any help around APIs would be greatly appreciated, how can I solve my reading of API data to work consistently?

// Sorry if the question is hard to understand I am not good at explaining the problem...

[Working result of the checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVEI9.png)

[Failed result of the  checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMGg.png)

Comment: `CheckUsernames` is `void` so cannot be awaited. That is likely the cause of your issue -> return a `Task` and await that.

Comment: Aside, style comment: `if (response.Contains("name") == true)` is usually written simply `if (response.Contains("name"))`.

Comment: `void` should only be used for asynchronous event handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working significantly more but it still skips the name occasionally, I have updated void to Task and removed true from response.Contains

Comment: Is _every_ `async` method being awaited? `async` should rise to the top of the call stack: there should be no `async void` methods.

Comment: Every async contains an await if that is what you mean, there are no async void methods.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at the official Mojang API documentation, and comparing it to the code you wrote, I notice that the whole authentication part is missing. Minecraft, starting from version **1.6**, has introduced a new scheme called **Yggdrasil**, which completely replaces the old one. Take a look, there might be some limits for "anonymous" calls.

Comment: Is that not only for logging into an account? I read that anonymous calls have 600 requests / 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Using `async` with void is not proper way to create `async` methods always use `async Task` in addition you can simply use

```
program.GetMojangItems(nameimput).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: What would I use that instead of?

Comment: private async Task CheckUsernames()

Comment: If you want to call an ```async``` ```Task``` from a synchronous method this is how you can do it. But if you can avoid doing that stick to async methods and don´t do that. Calling async methods from synchronous methods does not always work 'just fine'. You can introduce deadlocks and I´ve seen them fail in other ways. You´re not gonna have to solve those problems when you stick to ```async```.

Comment: There are many articles about this too. This is one of the first once that comes up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming. Though this is from 2013 the APIs didn´t change and even if they did the concepts don´t change. It´s not a C# problem either, you see the same thing happen in other languages that have asynchronous programming, like kotlins coroutines for instance.